# HTTP Connections from MarkLogic Java Client API run into deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, jersey, marklogic, jersey-client

After some stress testing our Java based middle ware accessing the MarkLogic server via the Java client API, I run in the situation where no more HTTP connections can be opened and a deadlock situation occurs. I am making use of one `DatabaseClient` shared instance, but create a `JSONDocumentManager` on each request (with a `JacksonHandle` for reading, no specific closing concern handled). Might there be an issue that connections are not closed properly or do I have to care on my own?

By looking at `netstat` at the point from which no more connections can be handled, I do see exactly 109 connections to the MarkLogic server (running on `localhost:8040`) in `FIN_WAIT_2`:

```
ffffff8045f765a0 31c91c01 tcp4       0      0  localhost.8040     localhost.65396    FIN_WAIT_2
```

and the same number (109) of TCP connections in `CLOSE_WAIT`:

```
ffffff804ff83400 73965e73 tcp4       0      0  localhost.49286    localhost.8040     CLOSE_WAIT
```

I am using MarkLogic server 7.0.4 with Java 1.7 (Mac OSX 10.9.5) and MarkLogic client API 2.0.4. Here is the first part of the thread dump (there are 10 similar threads seeming to wait on the server response):

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-10" #31 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc61f344000 nid=0x7c03 waiting on condition [0x00000001265bb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007a59cfff8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.WaitingThread.await(WaitingThread.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(ConnPoolByRoute.java:398)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute$1.getPoolEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:298)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:238)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:423)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:170)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DigestChallengeFilter.handle(DigestChallengeFilter.java:34)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPDigestAuthFilter.handle(HTTPDigestAuthFilter.java:493)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:507)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.getDocumentImpl(JerseyServices.java:612)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.getDocument(JerseyServices.java:568)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.read(DocumentManagerImpl.java:270)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.read(DocumentManagerImpl.java:204)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.read(DocumentManagerImpl.java:164)
    at com.acme.dashboard.service.ReportMetadataRepository.getByName(ReportMetadataRepository.java:64)
```

Further details of the stack trace left out for better readability.
After looking at JerseyServices I tried also to tweak the following system properties (unfortunately without any improvements):

```
com.marklogic.client.maximumRetrySeconds: 3 (default: 120)
com.marklogic.client.minimumRetries: 3 (default: 8)
```

Comment: What does netstat show?

Comment: @EJP around 220 connections (half of them in state `FIN_WAIT_2`, the other half `CLOSE_WAIT`, see my second and third para ;)

Comment: Can you share what handle you're passing to JSONDocumentManager.read?  If it's a streaming handle (one with a close() method) you'll need to be sure you're closing the handle when you're done with it.

Comment: Are you facing a deadlock scenario?  As in, if the requests stop do the threads never complete?  Or are you just showing us a snapshot during many concurrent requests?

Comment: @SamMefford I am using `JacksonHandle` and `TuplesHandle`, of which both seem not to have a close method available. And yes I am running into a deadlock scenario (let me clarify this in my question). Thanks.

Comment: CLOSE_WAIT means that the remote application has closed its end and the system is waiting for the local application to close its end. If you have a lot it indicates a bug in the local application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may be encountering a bug with JacksonHandle and TuplesHandle not closing their connections (github issue [#89](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues/89)).  This was fixed in Java Client API 2.0.5.  Are you able to run your tests on a 7.0-5 instance of ML Server and use the 2.0.5 version of the Java Client API?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sam! Unfortunately the production server will take some while to be updated, can you confirm that using Java Client API 2.0.5 with MarkLogic server 7.0-4 is able to work?

Comment: I have now stress tested our app with Client API 2.0.5 and Server 7.0-4 and it does work successfully (closing the HTTP connections properly). Thanks again, @sam-mefford

Answer (score 3):

Sockets in FIN_WAIT and CLOSE_WAIT can occur for many reasons, including kernel problems (known).

I would start looking at a single connection from start to end to make sure it is closing the socket and that the server is as well - you should see the state transition from FIN_WAIT to nothing fairly quickly  if both sides close the connection.
A common problem is code paths that don't close the connection.  You cant count on GC doing this, it will eventually finalize objects but often not soon enough.
Check to verify you are releasing your DatabaseClient.
How long do you keep it open ?

The examples I see in the Cookbooks and docs show it being used for fairly short duration before being closed.

Also check your thread count vs the # of threads configured on the server port.  If you are sending more concurrent requests then the server is configured for then you can reach a deadlock state like this using a single client.

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually I am using exactly one `DatabaseClient` instance for all requests (I consider it thread-safe, and resource expensive from what the javadoc state). I am not dealing with any closing of search handles resp. query/document managers yet, since their APIs seem not to require it, at least that was my understanding up to now.

Comment: I will have a look at the server configuration, also increase the logging to see wether MarkLogic's ErrorLog will point out some interesting points to follow up...